# SwiftUI Animation Not Working When View Removed

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, swiftui

SwiftUI Animate View Removal Not Working

I'm struggling with the animation modifiers on SwiftUI Views.

I have a mapping function in SwiftUI with MKMapView ViewRepresentable. I have an
annotation with two controls. The code for animation listed here and the
ComboDetailMapView below does indeed animate correctly for presentation of the
subview - but nothing I have tried animates the view as it is removed.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == view.leftCalloutAccessoryView {
        //this animates in - but does NOT animate out - required here for ANY animation
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
            parent.userDefaultsManager.showAddRemoveWaypointsView.toggle()
        }

    } else if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        //this animates in - but does NOT animate out - required in this place
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
            parent.userDefaultsManager.displayAddressView.toggle()
    }
    //...bunch more stuff
}
```

The view that I am animating is a simple white background image with opacity variation
and an alert style subview.

```
struct DisplayAddressView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userDefaultsManager: UserDefaultsManager
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                VStack {
                Image("PlainMask")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height + 20, alignment: .center)
                    .opacity(0.9)
                }//vstack
            }//geo reader

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.blue).opacity(0.3)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    //animation command does not work here
                    //withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {
                    self.userDefaultsManager.displayAddressView.toggle()
                }) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Approximate Address")
                            //.font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.system(size: 20) )
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        Divider()
                        Text(self.userDefaultsManager.approximateAddress)
                            //.font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .font(.system(size: 20) )
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
                Divider()
                Button(action: {
                    //animation command does not work here
                    //withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)) {}
                    self.userDefaultsManager.displayAddressView.toggle()
                }) {

                    Text("Dismiss")
                        //.font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .font(.system(size: 20) )
                }
            }
        }//Zstack
    }//body
}
```

And this is the view that launches the DisplayAddressView view:

```
struct ComboDetailMapView: View {

    @ObservedObject var userDefaultsManager: UserDefaultsManager
    var aTrip: Trip?

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text(aTrip?.name ?? "Unknown Map Name")
                    .padding(.top, -50)
                    .padding(.bottom, -20)
                DetailMapView(userDefaultsManager: userDefaultsManager, aTrip: aTrip)
                    .padding(.top, -20)
                Text(self.userDefaultsManager.tripTimeAndDistance)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }//vstack

            if userDefaultsManager.displayAddressView {
                DisplayAddressView(userDefaultsManager: userDefaultsManager)
                //this works to add slide to the other animation
                .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .slide))
                //this does not work for dismissal
                //.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .slide), removal: .scale))
            }
        }//zstack
    }//body
}
```

[image]

I've also tried the ideas of this SO 59064231 .No joy.

I confess the procedure to animate views since you can no longer attach the modifier
directly to the view is still confusing me. Any guidance would be appreciated.
Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504)

Comment: basically it is easier if there is an copyable and reproducable example to work on ...so i would suggest to break down to a reproducable example which people would like to help on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that if you step back and think about the functionality that I require here, I can simply use a ternary to control the position of the view. No if statement needed to compare the binding, no complex .transition coordination. As a bonus, opacity can be animated too if desired.

```
DisplayAddressView(userDefaultsManager: userDefaultsManager)
    .offset(x: userDefaultsManager.showAddressView ? 0 : 500)
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
```

Slick.